# Trading US stocks from India with SSN

Tags: united-states, stocks, india, international-trading

I had come to US for my masters and have an SSN. I would be returning back to India.

1. Can I trade US stocks from India using my US stock brokerage(TD Ameritrade) ?
2. When I pay taxes to IRS can I take deductions for my home office in India beacuse that is where I work.

Comment: Why would he even need to pay any taxes to IRS in that case?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure that #1 is true. I've never had difficulties trading from every country I travel to. There is a short list of countries that are not allowed - such as Cuba, Syria, etc. Nowhere a good VPN can't get around. Once you have an account, the trading company doesn't really care as long as you're not breaking laws.

As for #2, it's probably not worth the paperwork. And the answer is probably no.